# Using another scroll view to scroll tableview, cells aren't loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a weird requirement for UI, and need to scroll a table view in a page view using the scroll view I embed the page view in. For example:

```
import UIKit

class TableVC: UIViewController {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTableView()
    }

    func setupTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2000)
        ])


        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        tableView.backgroundColor = .blue

        let handler = { (tableView: UITableView, change: NSKeyValueObservedChange<CGSize>) in
            if let contentSize = change.newValue {
                print("contentSize:", contentSize)
            }
        }
        observer = tableView.observe(\UITableView.contentSize, options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new], changeHandler: handler)
    }

}

extension TableVC: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        50.0
    }

}

extension TableVC: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
        return cell
    }

}
```

And the main view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private enum Constants {
        static let pageViewControllerOptions: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey: Any] = [
            .interPageSpacing: CGFloat(8.0)
        ]
    }

    private let pageVC: UIPageViewController = UIPageViewController(
        transitionStyle: .scroll,
        navigationOrientation: .horizontal,
        options: Constants.pageViewControllerOptions
    )

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.pin(to: view)

        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.frame = view.bounds
        stackView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        let blueView = UIView()
        blueView.backgroundColor = .blue
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(blueView)
        blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true

        addChild(pageVC)
        pageVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        let pageView = pageVC.view!
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(pageView)
        pageVC.setViewControllers([TableVC()], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

        // 50 height with 20 cells works fine
        // 50 height with 40 cells won't work beacuse it doesn't seem to load them all
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 2000 + 100)

    }

}
```

With 40 cells I am expecting a content size of 2000, I set this above (allowing for the height of the blue view also). The scrolling works but it seems like at some point it has stopped generating the cells:

[image]

In the gif above you can see there are less than 40 cells. I have tried using a larger table view height, calling `layoutIfNeeded` but the result is the same. Is there anything I can do to fix this? I imagine the cells are not loading because I am not using the table view's own scroll view so `cellForRow` isn't triggered. Is there another way to load the cells?

Comment: Hi Kex in your cellforRowAt why are you not using tableview.dequereusablecell method to create cells, try using it and then check, I guess this might be the problem!

Comment: Tried this thanks, no different.

Comment: But why you don't scroll it with the KVO from the scroll view? I mean on offset change of the scroll view to cal self.tableView.setContentOffset(newPoint, animated: false) and then you will need to call layoutIfNeeded() of the table view.